# How much space and processing will be optimized in Lucene index by storing a field as Byte instead of String for billions of documents

Tags: algorithm, lucene, nlp, information-retrieval

I understand the concept of inverted-index and how Dictionary storage optimization could help to load entire dictionary in main memory for the faster query.

I am trying to understand how Lucene index work.

Suppose I have a String type field which has only four distinct values for the 200 billion documents indexed in Lucene. This field is a Stored field.

If I change the field to Byte or Int type to represent all 4 distinct values and re-index and store all the 200 billion documents.

What would be storage and query optimization for this data type change? If there would be any.

Please suggest if I can do some test on my laptop to get a sense.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a document in Lucene consists of a simple list of field-value pairs. A field must have at least one value, but any field can contain multiple values. Similarly, a single string value may be converted into multiple values by the analysis process.

> Lucene doesn’t care if the values are strings or numbers or dates. All
>   values are just treated as opaque bytes.

For more information, please see [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html).